# States surrounding/adjacent to a given state

Tags: geography

I want a function that gives a list of all states adjacent to a given state. How can I do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_] := AdministrativeDivisionData[x, "BorderingStates"]
```

Use:

`f[{"California", "UnitedStates"}]`

```
{Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Oregon", "UnitedStates"}], 
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Nevada", "UnitedStates"}], 
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Arizona", "UnitedStates"}]}
```